# How to intuitively understand this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is a limit that bugged me for more than three or four days:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac x{x^3}=\infty.$$

How is that possible? I would think that this goes to zero but the answer is infinity, how?

Comment: What happens when you simplify the fraction?

Comment: $x/x^3 = 1/x^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $x\to0$, $x$ goes to zero, but $x^3$ will tend to zero *faster*. You may have the false notion that $x^3\gt x$ because of comparing big numbers. But as we approach $0$, $x^3$ will start to become smaller and smaller than $x$, starting from $1$ as the following graph shows:

$\phantom{kkkkXX}$[image: Plot made by your humble correspondent Hakim ;-)]

Furthermore, we can cancel out one $x$ to have a $1/x^2$ which obviously and intuitively tends to **positive** infinity. $($ since $x^2\geqslant0)$
 We can illustrate this case using
[L'Hopital's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html)
since we have a $0/0$ case: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac1{3x^2}=\ldots$$
Finally, the graph of $x/x^3$:

$\phantom{XkkkkXX}$[image: Plot made by your humble correspondent Hakim ;-)]

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: thank you man! appreciate your effort!

Comment: @limitsintermsofx You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 3):

HINT : $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 1):

What is 
$$\frac1{(.1)^2}?$$
$$\frac1{(.01)^2}?$$
$$\frac1{(.001)^2}?$$
$$...$$
$$\frac1{(.000000000000001)^2}?$$
HINT:
$$\frac1{(.1)^2}=\frac1{\frac1{10^2}}=100$$